# How to change kafkastore.timeout.ms either in code or in YAML file

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

Does anyone have a sample code of how to change the `kafkastore.timeout.ms` either in code or in YAML configuration.

Thanks,

Austin

Comment: Why don't you just change it in the `schema-registry.properties` file?

Comment: I cannot, I don't have access to the server and we might run it from a docker image. May be to overwrite  the value in the YAML  the best option.